# QDateTime Conversion

Tags: qt, qdatetime

I need to convert the String variable to QDateTime format

my code looks

```
QString date ="Thu Jun 18 2015";
QDateTime tmp = QDateTime::fromString(date,"ddd MMM dd yyyy HH:mm:ss");
```

But the result is `Thu Jan 1 00:00:00 1970`.

Later I have to convert this date in to foramt `yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss`, so as a first step I have convert the string in to `QDateTime` then I have to convert to the final format, is there anything mistake with the above code?

Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks
Haris

Comment: The day names are localized according to the system's default locale settings, have you checked that?

Comment: I didn't get you point?

Comment: Other than the locale settings your `date` string does not include a time, while you mentioned that you want one, this will fail at least in Qt 5.4 . I still wonder thoguh why the epoch is printed. Maybe that depends on the qt version you are using.

Comment: I am using QT 5.4.1 MSVC 2013 64 bit, Actually my input will be like that only, so are you saying this can create problem when I deploying my application from system to another, where system locale settings can be different.

Comment: @Haris exactly, see my answer for a way to make your code independent of the system's locale.

Comment: Thanks I will refer it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your `date` string does not include a time, while you mentioned that you want one, this will fail at least in Qt 5.4 .
I don't know though why you get the epoche outputed, maybe that is dependant on your Qt version.

Your date format is also **locale dependent**.
See for example the doucmentation for `"ddd"` in [`QDateTime::fromString`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qdatetime.html#fromString-2):

> the abbreviated localized day name (e.g. 'Mon' to 'Sun'). Uses QDate::shortDayName().

Which unfortunately is not that clear, while it is more clear for [`QDateTime::toString`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qdatetime.html#toString):

> the abbreviated localized day name (e.g. 'Mon' to 'Sun'). Uses the system locale to localize the name, i.e. QLocale::system().

For example, in my locale (German, Austria) "ddd" for Thursday results in `"Do."` which is different from `"Thu"` and makes it impossible to parse English abbrevations with that locale.

To ensure you are using the correct locale when reading or writing locale dependent output use [`QLocale`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qlocale.html).
In your case that would be [`QLocale::toDateTime`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qlocale.html#toDateTime-2):

```
QLocale locale(QLocale::English, QLocale::UnitedStates);
QDateTime dt = locale.toDateTime("Jun 18 2015", "MMM dd yyyy");
```

Then if you also want locale dependent output use [`QLocale::toString`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qlocale.html#toString-7).